# jQuery undefined value of an existing html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery code to check whether a html element  with particular id exists or not. I have written the if and else clause of existing and non existing html element. But when the element exists why jQuery returns the value as undefined ?

You can see the jQuery code below. The variable start_time is defined, because it enters the clause condition but the value is detected as undefined. What is wrong with the code?

```
  var count = 0;
        for(i=1; i<=n_day; i++){

            count = count + 1 ;

            var start_time = jQuery("#txtStartTime_detail"+i);
            var end_time = jQuery("#txtEndTime_detail"+i);
            var start_location = jQuery("#txtStartLocation_detail"+i);
            var end_location = jQuery("#txtEndLocation_detail"+i);
            var start_location_coor = jQuery('#txtStartLocation_Coordinates_detail'+i);
            var end_location_coor = jQuery('#txtEndLocation_Coordinates_detail'+i);
            //var day = jQuery('#txtDay'+i);

            if(typeof start_time ==  'undefined'){
                start_time = '';
            }else{
                start_time = jQuery("#txtStartTime_detail"+i).val();
                alert(start_time);
            }
            if(typeof end_time ==  'undefined'){
                end_time = '';
            }else{
                end_time = jQuery("#txtEndTime_detail"+i).val();
            }
            if(typeof start_location ==  'undefined'){
                start_location = '';
            }else{
                start_location = jQuery("#txtStartLocation_detail"+i).val();
            }
            if(typeof end_location ==  'undefined'){
                end_location = '';
            }else{
                end_location =  jQuery("#txtEndLocation_detail"+i).val();
            }
            if(typeof start_location_coor ==  'undefined'){
                start_location_coor = '';
            }else{
                start_location_coor = jQuery('#txtStartLocation_Coordinates_detail'+i).val();
            }
            if(typeof end_location_coor ==  'undefined'){
                end_location_coor = '';
            }else{
                end_location_coor = jQuery('#txtEndLocation_Coordinates_detail'+i).val();
            }

                requestdetail += '<div class="yellow" id="txtDay'+count+'">Day - '+count+' : '+travel_date+'</div>'
                                +'<div class="table-responsive table-condensed">'
                                    +'<table class="table borderless">'
                                        +'<tbody>'
                                            +'<tr>'
                                                +'<td class="col-left">Travel time</td>'
                                                +'<td class="col-middle"><input type="text" name="txtStartTime_detail[]" id="txtStartTime_detail"'+count+'" class="timepicker" value="'+start_time+'"/></td>'
                                                +'<td class="col-middle"><input type="text" name="txtEndTime_detail[]" id="txtEndTime_detail'+count+'" class="timepicker" value="'+end_time+'" /></td>'
                                                +'<td class="col-right"><div class="error" id="error_time'+count+'">&nbsp;</div></td>'
                                            +'</tr>'
                                            +'<tr>'    
                                                +'<td class="col-left">Location</td>'
                                                +'<td class="col-middle-2"><input type="text" size="100" name="txtStartLocation_detail[]" id="txtStartLocation_detail'+count+'" class="inputWithImge" value="'+start_location+'" onmouseover="display_text(this)" />'
                                                +   '<img src="'+base_url+'" class="location-icon" alt="Click to search the location" name="location-icon" value="StartLocation_detail'+count+'" title="Click to show map"/>'   
                                                + '</td>'
                                                +'<td class="col-middle-2"><input type="text" name="txtEndLocation_detail[]" id="txtEndLocation_detail'+count+'" class="inputWithImge" value="'+end_location+'" onmouseover="display_text(this)"/>'
                                                +   '<img src="'+base_url+'" class="location-icon" alt="Click to search the location" name="location-icon" value="EndLocation_detail'+count+'" title="Click to show map"/>'     
                                                + '</td>'
                                                +'<td class="col-right"><div class="error" id="error_location'+count+'">&nbsp;</div></td>'
                                            +'</tr>'
                                        +'</tbody>'
                                        +'<input type="hidden" name="txtStartLocation_Coordinates_detail[]" id="txtStartLocation_Coordinates_detail'+count+'" value="'+start_location_coor+'">'
                                        +'<input type="hidden" name="txtEndLocation_Coordinates_detail[]" id="txtEndLocation_Coordinates_detail'+count+'" value="'+end_location_coor+'">'
                                    +'</table>'
                                +'</div>';

            travel_date = new Date(jQuery("#txtStartDate").val());
            travel_date.setDate(startDate.getDate() + i);
            travel_date = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate("DD, MM d, yy", new Date(travel_date));


    }
```

the html elements are populated dynamically in codeigniter and returns to browsers as a html String.

here is how I display the html string :

```
<form name="frm_RRequest" action="#" method="post">
                    <?php 
                        if(strlen($current_request)>0 || $current_request!=null){
                            echo $current_request;
                            echo '<div><input type="button" name="btn_Update" class="button" value="Update" /></div>';
                        }else{
                            $site_url = site_url("user/recommendation_request");
                            echo '<div class="yellow">you have no current request, you can make a new request here >> <a href="'.$site_url.'">Recommendation Request</a></div>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </form>
```

and here is how the elements are created in codeigniter

```
'<div class="yellow" id="txtDay'.$count.'">Day - '.$count.' : '.$travel_date.'</div>'
                            .'<div class="table-responsive table-condensed">'
                                .'<table class="table borderless">'
                                    .'<tbody>'
                                        .'<tr>'
                                            .'<td class="col-left">Travel time</td>'
                                            .'<td class="col-middle"><input type="text" name="txtStartTime_detail[]" id="txtStartTime_detail"'.$count.'" class="timepicker" value="'.$start_time.'"/></td>'
                                            .'<td class="col-middle"><input type="text" name="txtEndTime_detail[]" id="txtEndTime_detail'.$count.'" class="timepicker" value="'.$end_time.'" /></td>'
                                            .'<td class="col-right"><div class="error" id="error_time'.$count.'">&nbsp;</div></td>'
                                        .'</tr>'
                                        .'<tr>'    
                                            .'<td class="col-left">Location</td>'
                                            .'<td class="col-middle-2"><input type="text" size="100" name="txtStartLocation_detail[]" id="txtStartLocation_detail'.$count.'" class="inputWithImge" value="'.$row->start_location.'" onmouseover="display_text(this)" />'
                                            .   '<img src="'.$base_url.'" class="location-icon" alt="Click to search the location" name="location-icon" value="StartLocation_detail'.$count.'" title="Click to show map"/>' 
                                            . '</td>'
                                            .'<td class="col-middle-2"><input type="text" name="txtEndLocation_detail[]" id="txtEndLocation_detail'.$count.'" class="inputWithImge" value="'.$row->end_location.'" onmouseover="display_text(this)"/>'
                                            .   '<img src="'.$base_url.'" class="location-icon" alt="Click to search the location" name="location-icon" value="EndLocation_detail'.$count.'" title="Click to show map"/>'       
                                            . '</td>'
                                            .'<td class="col-right"><div class="error" id="error_location'.$count.'">&nbsp;</div></td>'
                                        .'</tr>'
                                    .'</tbody>'
                                    .'<input type="hidden" name="txtStartLocation_Coordinates_detail[]" id="txtStartLocation_Coordinates_detail'.$count.'" value="'.$start_location_coor.'">'
                                    .'<input type="hidden" name="txtEndLocation_Coordinates_detail[]" id="txtEndLocation_Coordinates_detail'.$count.'" value="'.$end_location_coor.'">'
                                .'</table>'
                            .'</div>';
```

Comment: First of all jquery objects wont be undefined. :|

Comment: Not related, but you know you can also write $ instead of jQuery, right? :)

Comment: edited my question. it should be html element. I think not because $ or jQuery. because other elements work fine. Just not working on some elements.

Comment: And what are those html elements? `.val()` is supposed to be used primarily with form elements.

Comment: edited my question. I just wonder, there are if and else conditions. If the element is undefined or does not exist it should enter if condition but it is otherwise. Still the value of an existing element is undefined

Comment: you should check whether element exist or not using the length properties.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the strings that you use to create the content.

You have

```
... id="txtStartTime_detail"'+count+'".....
```

which will create the ID

```
...id = "txtStartTime_detail"1"...
```

You just have to remove the extra double quotes `"'+count"'` should be `'+count+'"`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Anyway, when the element does not exist it still returns with undefined despite having the if and else clause. length does not work in my case. typeof works for existing elements but not non existed one

Comment: jQuery() should return an array of length 0 if nothing is found. Also if checking for undefined you can just have `if(startTime === undefined){` its quicker and easy to read. You can replace `jQuery(...)` with `$(...)` they are the same function. Use the Console to find out what is going on. I would add `console.log(start_time);` and then see what you are gettting. Then I would look at the function, you may have corrupted it. Add `console.log(jQuery);` befor the loop and it should return the function. If not then you have corrupted it somehow.